# python kivy garden knob - how to override on_knob

Tags: python, kivy

Using Kivy.garden.knob, and having an issue:
I'm trying to post the knob value to the command line when I move it, but I'm unable to make it work, any suggestions?
Here the whole code, thanks in advance, FD.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from threading import Thread
from cmd import Cmd
import logging
logging.getLogger("kivy").disabled = True


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.garden.knob import  Knob
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class FirstTimeConnect(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstTimeConnect, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)

        layout.knob1 = Knob(knobimg_source="/Users/admin/Dropbox/Strumenti/Concatenativa_PyCpp/knob_img/knob_black.png", marker_img="/Users/admin/Dropbox/Strumenti/Concatenativa_PyCpp/knob_img/bline.png")
        layout.add_widget(layout.knob1)

        def on_knob(self, value):
            print "hi"
        layout.knob1.bind(on_knob=on_knob)

        self.add_widget(layout)

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(FirstTimeConnect(name='First Time Connect'))

class MyCmd(Cmd, object):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        #return LogScreen()
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    Thread(target=app.run()).start()
    MyCmd(app).cmdloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override a method in a widget/class you need to *inherit* from the class. The thing you did is "overriding" `on_knob` method of `Screen` and as `Screen` has no such method as `on_knob`, it just created a new one.

```
class MyKnob(Knob):
    def on_knob(self, value):
        print("hello!")
```

Also notice that there's no property `knob` and that it's bound kind of "manually" with [`_value`](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.knob/blob/master/__init__.py#L224). In a casual Kivy behavior `on_*` methods are *events* and to override them you'd need to do this:

```
class MyKnob(Knob):
    def on_my_property(self, <arguments if it has any>):
        super(MyKnob, self).on_my_property(<arguments>)
        print("hello!")
```

depending on what you want to execute first i.e.

- old behavior + your print (`super` + `print`)
- your print + old behavior (`print` + `super`)

In case of completly rewriting it, just remove `super()` from the method and it won't do the default behavior e.g. let's say if you override `on_touch_down` with this:

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        pass
```

there will be no touch event if a touch collides with an area of your widget (if you touch the widget).